# Validating topology using python script when ArcMap is open?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, topology, schema-locks

I am testing on validating topology using python.The situation is when I run the script when arcmap is open, an error occurs which indicates the topology has already been opened (FDO error: -2147214980 Cannot acquire a schema lock because of an existing lock), but when I close arcmap,the error disappear and it works properly.

Does it means I can't validate a topology when arcmap is open?

Answer (score 1):

You can only validate the topology from ArcMap if it has it open. This is because of exclusive schema locks that ArcMap places on the geodatabase and to validate the topology the database has to be written to...

If you are using enterprise database you would still need to get all the editors out before validating.

You can put your python script on a tool and execute it from ArcMap but this would be the same as pressing the 'validate topology' button.

Comment: Hi Michael, my question is if put the python srcipt on a tool, is it possible that user only click once on the menu? Is it from arctoolbox? thank you.

Comment: Hi Michael, don't know whether you may see this comment. My reqirement is allow several users to edit the map and validate the topology relationship between 2 feature class. Besides using the topology tool, what else can I use to check the topology relationship between 2 feature class. Thank you!